# Rock Paper Scissors - How do I Make a User Select an Option AND THEN use a "GO" button to execute the random choice?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help in linking my javascript and HTML! I need to force the user to click one of the radio buttons (rock, paper, or scissors) to confirm their choice, AND THEN click a "GO!" button to execute the computer's randomizing function. In the end, it will display to the user whether they lost, won, or tied. I don't know how to connect the user's choice to the computer's randomized choice to determine their win/lose/tie...

Basically: what functions in my JS should I add to do this, especially to compare the user's input to the computer-generated choice?

Here's my snippet for the button form:

```js
function play() {
    var types = ['rock','paper','scissors']
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(types.length));
    document.getElementById('choiceDisplay').onclick = types[random];
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="stuff">
    <h2> Select one: </h2>
    <div class="choices">
    <p> 
    <form>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" value="paper"">Paper
    <br>
    <input type="radio" value="scissors">Scissors
    </form>
    </p>
    </div>
    <p id="choiceDisplay"></p>
    <button onclick="play()">GO!</button>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

<html>
```

Comment: Why do you have two `</html>`? And where is the `Rock` button?

Comment: The value you assign to `onclick` should be a function, not a string. What are you expecting `onclick = types[random];` to do?

Comment: You have an extra quote in `value="paper""`

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to give your radio buttons a name. Radio buttons are grouped by all having the same name. E.g.

```
<input name="choice" type="radio" value="paper">Paper
```

2. You're missing the Rock button.
3. There's no need to assign anything to the `onclick` property of the radio buttons. Just set a variable to the random selection from the array to get the computer's choice:

```
computer_choice = types[ Math.floor(Math.random()*(types.length))];
```

You can get the value of the user's selection with:

```
var user_button = document.querySelector("input[name=choice]:checked");
if (user_button) {
    var user_choice = user_button.value;
} else {
    alert("You have to choose Rock, Paper, or Scissoer first");
}
```

Then you can compare the user's choice to the computer's choice to determine the winner.

```js
function play() {
  var types = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  var computer_choice = types[Math.floor(Math.random() * (types.length))];
  document.getElementById("choiceDisplay").innerText = computer_choice;
  var user_button = document.querySelector("input[name=choice]:checked");
  if (user_button) {
    var user_choice = user_button.value;
  } else {
    alert("You have to choose Rock, Paper, or Scissoer first");
    return;
  }
  if (user_choice == computer_choice) {
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Tie";
    return;
  }
  switch (computer_choice) {
    case "rock":
      if (user_choice == "paper") {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Paper covers rock, you win!";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Rock breaks scissors, you lose!";
      }
      break;
    case "paper":
      if (user_choice == "scissors") {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Scissors cut paper, you win!";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Paper covers rock, you lose!";
      }
      break;
    case "scissors":
      if (user_choice == "rock") {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Rock breaks scissors, you win!";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Scissors cut paper, you lose!";
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="stuff">
  <h2> Select one: </h2>
  <div class="choices">
    <p>
      <form>
        <input name="choice" type="radio" value="rock">Rock
        <br>
        <input name="choice" type="radio" value="paper">Paper
        <br>
        <input name="choice" type="radio" value="scissors">Scissors
      </form>
    </p>
  </div>
  <p>Computer plays: <span id="choiceDisplay"></span></p>
  <p>Result: <span id="result"></span></p>
  <button onclick="play()">GO!</button>
  <script src="game.js"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a winner could probably be cleaned up, but this is a quick and dirty way to do it.

```js
// get all the buttons
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
// add a click handler to each
buttons.forEach(
    button => button.addEventListener('click', event => go(event))
);

function go(event) {
  // get the human choice from the click event
  const human = event.currentTarget.id;
  // have the computer pick one at random
  const computer = pickThrow();
  // figure out the winner
  const result = chooseWinner(human, computer);
  // report the results
  alert(`Human had ${human}. Computer had ${computer}. ${result}`);
}

function pickThrow() {
  const items = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  return items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
}

function chooseWinner(human, computer) {
  let result;
  if (human === computer) return "Tie!";
  if (human === "rock") {
    return computer === "scissors" ? "Human Wins!" : "Computer Wins!"
  }
  if (human === "paper") {
    return computer === "rock" ? "Human Wins!" : "Computer Wins!";
  }
  if (human === "scissors") {
    return computer === "paper" ? "Human Wins!" : "Computer Wins!";
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button id="rock">Rock</button>
<button id="paper">Paper</button>
<button id="scissors">Scissors</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Your game.js must be included

```js
// your game.js
function play() {
  var types = ['rock','paper','scissors']
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(types.length));
  document.getElementById('choiceDisplay').innerHTML = types[random];
}

// Waiting untill the browser fully loaded HTML,
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Attach play function to the click event of the GO button
  document.getElementById("play").addEventListener( "click", play);
})
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="stuff">
  <h2> Select one: </h2>
  <div class="choices">
    <form>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="rock"/>Rock
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="scissors"/>Scissors
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="paper"/>Paper
      </label>
    </form>
  </div>
  <p id="choiceDisplay"></p>
  <button id="play">GO!</button>
</div>
</body>
<script src="game.js"></script>
</html>
```